# Datatables paging type is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging

Paging type in DataTable is not working:

[image]

Code in my controller:

```
$('#report1').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "sDom": 'lrtip',
    "sPagingType": "full_number",
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "info": false,
    "retrieve": true,
    "ajax": {
       'url':...
```

Code in my html-file

```
<table id="report1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" cellspacing="0"  width="100%"> ...</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sPaginationType` (v1.9+) or `pagingType` (v1.10+) to set pagination style.  Also one of the options is `full_numbers`, not `full_number`.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

or

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "pagingType": "full_numbers"
});
```

See [`pagingType`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) or [`sPaginationType`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) for more information.

Comment: I tried, but is not working. I changed the table, now I have an error-  


`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Happened!

[image]

I added in my index.html file-css from:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Thanks for help :)